# http server does not stop when I call listener.Close()

Tags: http, go, listener

I'm trying to write a http server which when received terminate signal, it will wait until all requests has been responsed then close with code below

```
// start server
var wg sync.WaitGroup
server := &http.Server{
    ConnState: func(conn net.Conn, state http.ConnState) {
        switch state {
        case http.StateNew:
            wg.Add(1)
        case http.StateClosed:
            wg.Done()
        }
    },
}

go func(server *http.Server, listener net.Listener, terminate chan<- int) {
    var status int
    if err := server.Serve(listener); err != nil {
        if !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "use of closed network connection") {
            log.Println(err)
            status = 1
        } else {
            status = 0
        }
    } else {
        status = 0
    }

    log.Printf("performing graceful close on all clients\n")
    wg.Wait()

    terminate <- status
}(server, listener, terminate)
```

but when I call `listener.Close()` it stuck at `wg.Wait()` even though all request has already been response. And while it wait, if I send another request, it still give a response correctly.

Comment: Most connections transition to `StateIdle`, not `StateClosed`

Comment: As JimB say. And you can change default behaviour with server.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem.